# Swift: Assigning array to value dictionary copies it?

Tags: swift

Consider this code, which assigns an array to a dictionary value and later appends to the array. (In practice it would loop over the characters in a string; this is the simplified version.)

```
var letterIndexes = [Character: [Int]]()

let letter: Character = "a"
var indexes: Array<Int>? = letterIndexes[letter]
if indexes == nil {
    indexes = Array<Int>()
    letterIndexes[letter] = indexes
}
indexes!.append(0)
```

The value of letterIndexes is now `[ "a": 0 elements ]`.

I would have expected it to be `[ "a": [ 0 ] ]`.

It looks like `letterIndexes[letter] = indexes` makes a copy of `indexes`. I want to avoid unnecessary lookups in the dictionary. If that weren't a concern, I could do `letterIndexes[letter]!.append(0)` after the if and it would work.

Have I misunderstood what's going on here? Am I doing something dumb?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html) states:

> A value type is a type whose value is copied when it is assigned to a variable or constant, or when it is passed to a function.

So when you assign `indexes` in

```
letterIndexes[letter] = indexes
```

it creates a copy of indexes, therefore appending to `indexes` will not modify `letterIndexes`.